# AngularJS Resource not using ID on update

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a pretty basic factory:

```
app.factory('Person', function($resource) {
return $resource(API_ROUTE+'/people/:id.json', {
  id: "@id"
}, {
  update: {
    method: "PUT"
  }
});
});
```

It performs a `get` request with the specified URL as expected, but when I tried to do an update, it goes to `/people.json` instead of `/people/:id.json`.

```
Person.get({
  id: personId
}, function(person) {
  return $scope.person = person;
});

$scope.person.$update()
```

The response I get from the server logs:

```
Started PUT "/hr/angular/people.json" for 128.104.86.165 at 2015-04-14 14:12:30 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/angular/people.json"):
```

I tried a different way of doing the update command but got the same response.

```
Person.update($scope.person, function(person) {
  console.log($person);
});
```

If I hardcode an id into the resource path, like `$resource(API_ROUTE+'/people/1234.json')`, I'm able to do all the expected actions on that individual, including update. I don't see what I'm missing that would allow the `get` method of a resource use the proper path but not an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your id Into the update method don't you?

```
$scope.person.$update({ id: 1 }, function(response) {
    //
});
```